# How do I write and read a archive in c?

Tags: c

I'm trying to write students' names and grades and read from inside the binary file, but it's not working.

I'm trying to do this without struct, because I didn't learn it yet.

Writing:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define Q 20 

FILE *arq;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char url[]="notas.bin";
    char *dmain[Q];
    arq = fopen(url,"wb");
    if(arq == NULL)
    {
        printf("Erro, nao foi possivel abrir o arquivo\n");
        exit(1);
    }


    for (int i = 1; i< argc; i++ )
    {
        dmain[i-1]=argv[i];
        printf("%s\n", dmain[i-1]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < Q; i++)
    {
        fwrite(dmain+i, sizeof(char), 1, arq);
    }
    

    fclose(arq);
}
```

Reading:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define Q 20
#define N 10

int main (){
    char url[]="notas.bin";
    char *nomes[N];
    int  cont, nota[N], recebe[Q];
    FILE *arq;

    arq = fopen(url, "rb");
    if(arq == NULL)
    {
        printf("Erro, nao foi possivel abrir o arquivo\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    cont = fread(recebe, sizeof(char), Q, arq);

    if (cont !=Q)
        fprintf (stderr, "Foram lidos apenas %d Elementos!!!\n" , cont) ;

    /* Apresentar os dados ao usuário */
    for (int i=0; i<Q; i++)
    printf ("%d N: %d \n", i+1, recebe[i]);

    fclose(arq);
}
```

This is still the prototype, I was writing and the reading is kind of sus with numbers repeating:

Sending the data:

```
PS C:\\Users\\gabri\\OneDrive\\Documentos\\GitHub\\Programacao1\\Exercicio 7\> & ."prog4_escrever_arquivo_bin_notas.exe" gabriel 90 pedro 80 sandra 70 brenda 80 tiago 60 barbara 60 maria 90 ana 60 vitor 90 caze 70
gabriel
90
pedro
80
sandra
70
brenda
80
tiago
60
barbara
60
maria
90
ana
60
vitor
90
caze
70
```

Reading the data:

```
PS C:\\Users\\gabri\\OneDrive\\Documentos\\GitHub\\Programacao1\\Exercicio 7\> & ."prog5_ler_arquivo_bin_notas.exe"
1 N: 1614815232
2 N: -524246912
3 N: 1614815232
4 N: -524246912
5 N: -533675952
6 N: 654
7 N: -151458356
8 N: 32763
9 N: 2
10 N: 654
11 N: 0
12 N: 0
13 N: 974291712
14 N: 654
15 N: 268501009
16 N: 227
17 N: 976422744
18 N: 654
19 N: -151528186
20 N: 32763
```

Comment: `fwrite(dmain+i, sizeof(char), 1, arq);` This only writes one character of each string.  So the contents of the file are going to be something like `g9p8s7b8...`

Comment: And same on reading. A char is one character.

Comment: To write a string, you need to write all the characters and either start with the length or end with a NUL so you know how long the string is when you read it.

Comment: and then you are reading the chars into an array of ints, where it looks like int is 4 bytes, and so 4 chars get combined into 1 int

Comment: Having a constant `Q` to make some arbitrary length array when you know *exactly* how long it should be (`argc`) is kind of pointless.

Comment: This is being fairly pedantic but a binary file is not _necessarily_ an archive.

Comment: So how can I put all the character in the file?

Comment: If you’re just reading and writing characters `fgetc` and `fputc` should work fine. Do keep in mind that these take and return unsigned characters. However, if you’re going to be using structs to read and write to binary files later then my suggestion would be to just learn them now. It is significantly easier to read and write to/from binary files with them.